# In Clojure, how can I branch logic depending on which keys are passed into a function?

Tags: clojure

I've got a function that needs to call slightly different logic depending on which keys are provided.  Right now I'm using this ugly "nested-if" structure.  Can someone show me a better, cleaner way to do this?

```
(defn myfunc
  "Do different things depending on which keys are given."
  [{:keys [a b c]}]
  ;; If (myfunc {:a})
  (if (not (nil? a))
    (do-a)
    ;; If (myfunc {:b})
    (if (not (nil? b))
      (do-b)
      ;; If (myfunc {:c})
      (if (not (nil? c))
        (do-c)
        ;; If none of the above keys are available, do d
        (do-d)))))
```

I could use `(contains? ...)` but then I would have to not specify the keys in the signature, and it doesn't really improve the nested structure.

Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
(defn myfunc
  "Do different things depending on which keys are given."
  [{:keys [a b c]}]
  (if (two-or-more-of [a b c])
      (some-error)
      (with
        :a (do-a arg1)
        :b (do-b arg2)
        :c (do-c arg1 arg2)
        else (do-d))))
```

Note:  I'm not good enough with macros to write one, but I would take someone else's if that's the right answer and someone wanted to =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write a macro, clojure has one for you. Use `cond` to get rid of your nested `if`

```
(defn myfunc
  [{:keys [a b c]}]
  (cond (two-or-more-of [a b c]) (some-error)
        (not (nil? a)) (do-a)
        (not (nil? b)) (do-b)
        (not (nil? c)) (do-c)
        :else (do-d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but I think it should work. You can also do it in a way closer to your original idea.

```
(defn myfunc
  [{:keys [a b c]}]
  (if (two-or-more-of [a b c])
    (some-error)
    (condp = (some identity [a b c])
      a (do-a)
      b (do-b)
      c (do-c)
      (do-d)))) ; default
```